# -lclsntsh not found in c++ connection with oracle programm

Tags: c++, linux, oracle

i've centos 6.4 as server and centos7.5 as client both in VM. I  am trying to connect
oracle 11gr2 with c++ using codeblocks. following  is code

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <oracle/11.2/client64/occi.h>
   #include <iomanip>
   using namespace oracle::occi;
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
       const string user="rahul", passwd = "rahul", connstring = "orcl";
       Environment *env =  Environment::createEnvironment();
       Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, passwd, connstring);
       string strstmt = "select *from emp";
       Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement(strstmt);
       ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
       while(rs->next())
       {
           cout <<  setw(4) << rs->getInt(1)  <<"  "<< setw(6) << rs->getString(2) << "  "
                 << setw(7) << rs->getString(3)<<"  "<<setw(4)<< rs->getInt(4) << setw(9)<<"     "
                < rs->getString(5)<< "  "<< setw(4) << rs->getInt(6) << "  " << setw(4)<< rs->
    tInt(7)<<"  "
                << setw(5) << rs->getInt(8)<<endl;
       }
       stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
       conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
       env->terminateConnection(conn);
       Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
       return 0;
   }
```

is shows following  errors :-

```
    -------------- Build: Debug in oraconn (compiler: GNU GCC   
    Compiler)---------------

    g++ -L/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2 -L/opt/oracle
    /instantclient_11_2 -o bin/Debug/oraconn obj/Debug/main.o   
    -lnnz11   -locci -lclntsh
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
    2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

i added these libs in project->build options -> linker settings. and in search directories  i added following

```
    usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
    opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include
```

also i added LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variables as :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib6
:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2; export PATH
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/network/admin; export TNS_ADMIN
CLASSPATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:
$CLASSPATH; export CLASSPATH
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2; export ORACLE_HOME
INCLUDEPATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/sdk/inclcue:$INCLUDEPATH; export 
INCLUDEPATH
```

Comment: Code block didn't add `-L/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64`.

Comment: i didn't get what you say

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or not, but the paths are missing `/`. The proper link command should have been `g++  -o bin/Debug/oraconn obj/Debug/main.o  -L/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -lclntsh -lnnz11 -locci`

Comment: i did it;ike this :-  g++ -o bin/Debug/oraconn obj/Debug/main.o -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -L/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib -lclntsh -lnnz11 -locci  this compiles but having error : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'oracle::occi::SQLException'
  what():  ORA-24960: the attribute  OCI_ATTR_USERNAME is greater than the maximum allowable length of 255

Comment: Uppercase `L`. but then you can fix your program now.

Comment: nothing happens  having same problem : -lclntsh  not found

Comment: Check where this library is located and add it to the library path.

Comment: i added this in LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 but not getting solution